# Show that the Hyperoctahedral Group is a semi-direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

I am confused about an exercise from *Representations of Finite Groups* by C.Musili (Exercise 7.10.1), which asks the reader to show that the hyperoctahedral group $B_n$ is a semi-direct product.

First I will include some definitions/notations from the book:

The hyperoctahedral group on $n$ signed letters, denoted $B_n$, is defined as the following subgroup of $S_{ \{1,...,n,-n,...,-1\} } \cong S_{2n}$.

$$ B_n = \{ \theta \in S_{2 n} \mid \theta(-i) = -\theta(i), 1 \leq i \leq n \} $$

Any element $\theta$ of $B_n$ is of the form
$$
\theta=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & \cdots & n & -n & \cdots & -1 \newline
\epsilon_1 \sigma(1) & \cdots & \epsilon_n \sigma(n) & -\epsilon_n \sigma(n) & \cdots & -\epsilon_1 \sigma(1)
\end{matrix}\right) \tag{1}
$$
for unique $\left(\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_n\right) \in N=C_2^n$ and unique $\sigma \in S_n$, where $C_2=$ $\{ \pm 1\}$ is the cyclic group of order 2 and $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $\{1, \cdots, n\}$.

It is worth noting that permutations are composed from right to left. That is $xy(k) = x(y(k))$.

The exercise is to show that this group is a semi-direct product. (The below is not a direct quote because I have moved in the definition of the semi-direct product from another chapter)

> Define the semi-direct product of $H$ by $N$ (denoted $G=N \bullet H$) as the set $G=N \times H$ along with the group multiplication given by $(a, x)(b, y)=(a(x \cdot b), x y)$ for all $a, b \in N$ and $x, y \in H$. Show that $B_n$ is the semi-direct product of $S_n$ by $N$, where $S_n$ acts on $N$ by permuting coordinates.

The only way I can show that the map described in (1) is an isomorphism is by taking the multiplication rule to instead be $(a, x)(b, y)=((y^{-1} \cdot a)b, x y)$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to find subgroups $N$ and $H$ of $B_n$ with $N \lhd B_n$, $NH=B_n$ and $N \cap H = \{1\}$. You could take $N$ to be the subgroup of order $2^n$ with $\theta(i) = \pm i$ for all $i$, and $H$ to be the subgroup of order $n!$ with $\theta(i) > 0$ for all $i>0$.